# pArray vs. pArray[0]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have

```
class Variable 
{ 
public:     
    double lb;  
}

class Variables 
{ 
public:      
    int numberOfVariables;
    Variable **var;
}
```

Now

```
cout << var[0]->lb;
```

gives me the expected behavior, but

```
cout << var->s;
```

does not work. In fact, it gives me the compile error: "request for member '..' in '..' which is of non-class type". I thought var and var[0] could be used interchangeably, and my debugger does indeed let me do it that way. What is going on?

I have a situation where I need a polymorphic object that can take either a single var element or an array of var. What is the best way to implement that?

Comment: I read it twice but what is s in var->s?

Comment: "I thought var and var[0] could be used interchangeably" - that's your problem. You thought wrong. In C++ language `var` is never equivalent to `var[0]` (assuming built-in `[]`)

Comment: `and my debugger does indeed let me do it that way.` A debugger is not the language spec.

Comment: `I need a polymorphic object that can take either a single var element or an array of var`  Why separate one var or `n` vars? Create a single function that takes a container of `n` vars -- if `n == 1`, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `var[i]` is equivalent to `*(var + i)`. So `var` is not the same as `var[0]`. `*var` is the same as `var[0]`. `var` is just a pointer to the start of the array, you must dereference the pointer. Look up pointers.

For your second question, look into `std::vector`. It dynamically changes size and handles all the low level memory management operations for you.